# Transmission asks if there is another version of transmission running

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, bittorrent, transmission

I have recently installed transmission daemon, while trying to config my user settings from the commadline, i noticed this line.
[04:07:41.304] Couldn't bind port 51413 on 0.0.0.0: Address already in use (Is another copy of Transmission already running?) (net.c:371)
Having already stopped the daemon /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon stop 
and successfully added sudo transmission-daemon -f -t -u username -v password -w ~/Downloads to create a user, not -g global config file. I am unable to find what it is still running. I did a uninstall of transmission and purged, reinstalled only the daemon, remote and cli, and still get the same message? could someone explain what is still running please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

51413 is in the [Ephemeral Port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port) range, therefore any application can dynamically use that port, even if it's not a server (outgoing connections bind to a dynamic port on the local interface).  I would recommend using a number lower than 32768 and higher than 1024 for all server applications, and look in /etc/services to avoid any assigned numbers, otherwise this problem can reoccur at any time randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run a new instance on a new port. For example:

```
transmission-cli -p 51414 <torrent URL>
```